# Adjust box position of \CheckBox

Tags: hyperref

I'm currently trying to create an interactive PDF with multi-line text to the left of a checkbox.

But unfortunately the default layout is a bit unattractive.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \CheckBox{Default CheckBox}\\

    \renewcommand{\LayoutCheckField}[2]{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr(\textwidth-\DefaultWidthofCheckBox-4pt)}{#1\vspace{0.1cm}} \mbox{#2}}
    \CheckBox{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
\end{document}
```

This creates an output like
[image: Current output]

As you can see, the checkmark icon is not in the center of the field.

I would prefer it would like this:
[image: Preferred output]

So basically:

- The box should have the width and height of the current line height of the font
- The checkmark icon should be centered within the box

Any idea how to solve this (I think I have to modify `\MakeCheckField` somehow)?

//Edit: I have now tried if changing the icon helps, but in that case, for example, Adobe Acrobat on Android says that the PDF is broken when I use the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        %see https://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf for the expected characters
        \foreach \x in {33, ..., 40}
        {
            \CheckBox[name=CheckBox\x,checkboxsymbol=\ding{\x}, checked=true]{\x}
        }
        \foreach \x in {42, ..., 126}
        {
            \CheckBox[name=CheckBox\x,checkboxsymbol=\ding{\x}, checked=true]{\x}
        }
        \foreach \x in {161, ..., 239}
        {
            \CheckBox[name=CheckBox\x,checkboxsymbol=\ding{\x}, checked=true]{\x}
        }
        \foreach \x in {241, ..., 254}
        {
            \CheckBox[name=CheckBox\x,checkboxsymbol=\ding{\x}, checked=true]{\x}
        }
        
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Preview of TeXStudio:

[image: TexStudio Preview]

Chromium based browser output:

[image: Chromium test]

Comment: you are a bit at the mercy of pdf viewers here (and I can't reproduce your output), but in general you have more control over the look if you use appearances, see l3pdffield-checkbox

Comment: You are right - it depends on the PDF viewer. The above output is generated by Chromium based browsers (PDFium). Under Acrobat on PC the icons are in the right place - but under Android Adobe Acrobat does not show any icon at all. I tried to work around this now by setting `checkboxsymbol`, but that doesn't seem to help much either. When I get all possible symbols from pifont, it still works with the Google Drive PDF viewer on Android, but Adobe Acrobat doesn't want to open them anymore, saying that the PDF is broken.